# Using MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard how can I connect to my MS SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, freetds

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 Guest and Windows 8.1 Host through Virtual Box.  I'm trying to migrate my database from SQL Server on my Windows Host to my MySQL server on my Ubuntu Guest.  Currently I can connect from my rails app on Ubuntu Guest to my SQL Server using freetds.  When I try to use the migration wizard though I get the following error.

```
Could not connect to Source DBMS.
[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

ODBC connection string: DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=192.168.1.111;PORT=1433;DATABASE=borneo;UID=marvin;PWD={*****************};TDS_VERSION=7.1
```

Reading I found some posts that said I needed to add some things to my odbc.ini file, but after adding the following, I still had the same results.

```
[borneo]
Description = borneo
Driver      = FreeTDS
SERVER      = 192.168.1.111
USER        = marvin
PASSWORD    = **********
PORT        = 1433
DATABASE    = borneo
Option      = 3
```

Comment: While this shouldn't be considered a "fix", I was able to get the information transferred over by created a mysql instance on the windows host and moving the database there.  Then connected to that instance from the ubuntu instance.